# Inserting rows into a database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, insert, datasource

I am new to .NET, and I'm can't seem to figure out something that should be simple. I want to insert a row into a table, and initialize it with values that aren't bound to data controls. Specifically, I have a CreateUserWizard control on a page. In the CreatedUser method, I want to insert a row into a databse I created called "users" that contains the Username and the Email address from the CreateUserWizard control, and the date the new user was created, from the DateTime.Now function. There doesn't seem to be a way to set the Parameters in the sqlDataSource control in a way that they can access data that is not bound to data controls. Can anyone explain a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the wrong track - you won't use the sqlDataSource control at all.  You'll go for a more direct interaction with the database from code. For example:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Table (P1, P2) Values (@P1, @P2)", conn);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P1", P1Value);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P2", P2Value);
cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Now, with that all being said, you'll want to learn the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader in some detail (they are pretty straightforward) and then turn your attention to building a Data Access Layer that makes sense to you. You'll be glad that you did.

Comment: ?? Who would downvote this answer and mark it offensive??  Someone must have a strange sense of humor.

Comment: That took care of the issue for me. Everything makes sense now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know how to vote . . . when I click on "VOTE" tab nothing happens.

Comment: Click the Up Arrow over the number to upvote an answer.  Click the down arrow below the number to downvote it (meaning - answer not helpful).  To accept an answer, click the check-mark outline on the left. The "Votes" tab lets you sort answers by the # of votes.

Comment: I checked it so that is shows the answer solved my problem. However, I don't have a 15 reputation (I'm new here), so it won't let me vote. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set defaults on the database itself, so that you don't need to worry about passing Datetime.now.

Comment: My personal preference is for datetimes like this to always be set at the server (using GETDATE()), fixes many issues with updates from multiple time zones.