# How to insert values into database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I have taken some text field and abd some labels and one submit and one reset button. I want to code like: when i enter some values in text boxes and click upon submit my record will get submitted into the database. And when i click upon reset then my form will get reset.

Please let me know how will i code this scenario.

Thanks,

Ashish

Comment: Go and try to do it yourself and then come back if you have specific problems, otherwise you are asking people here to do your work for you. Not a good way to learn.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate, this post has an example to get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600971/inserting-rows-into-a-database-in-asp-net

Comment: There are SOO many resources already that explain how to do this MANY different ways.  I would suggest googling it before posting a question.

Comment: Actually i know how to connect to the data base,
but i want to take some live example. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 5):

With due respect, this question is rather broad and you would likely be better served by doing a bit of searching for some base knowledge about the tasks that you are looking to perform.

I would suggest that you begin by going to your favorite search engine and querying for:

- HTML Forms
- Insert data into a database
- ASP.NET Tutorials

Once you have a grasp of the basic technologies that you're using, you should find that it is far easier to accomplish your task.  If, by chance, you run into any specific problems or issues, then this would be a great place to ask questions related to them.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net and databases
http://www.asp101.com/samples/db_add.asp

resetting the forms
http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Asp-Control/Resettheform.htm

you should try using google first.  these examples came up on top for simple queries like

```
asp.net databases
```

and

```
asp.net reset forms
```

that said you have not really provided enough information to garner a useful answer.
what database are you using, what version of asp.net (are you even using it, or did you click the tag by accident - you 
dont mention it in your post), what platform - specifically?

Comment: I am using sql 2005 and visual studio 2005